# Does Relevant Industry Experience help with PhD application in US for Applied Science Fields?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, physics, industry, electrical-engineering

I am now pursuing a master in Optics in Germany and decide to apply to PhD programs of Optics/Applied Physics/ECE in US for 2023fall. My research interest is on experimental quantum information. Here in Germany, the study programs of applied science fields like to encourage/require students to get experience in Industry. But I am worrying whether this kind of experience is helpful to PhD applications in US. The kind of work I am doing is like use the physics principle to come up with a design and implement XXX to achieve certain engineering objective, not very much research on the physics side. I have heard peers saying many people in US have years of working experience before they apply to Phd, so I am not in a favorable situation. Is it true?

Comment: This is our general Q&A for US PhD admissions: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38237/how-are-ph-d-applications-evaluated-in-the-us-particularly-for-weak-or-borderl The US has no national system for university education; admission is up to whatever the people serving on the admissions committee (professors, typically) want it to be. Broadly, you'll be evaluated based on the opinion of the people on the committee that you demonstrate excellent potential as a researcher; you'll be admitted if you're one of the top N applicants to the program that cycle.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Very useful, thank you. I didn't see this post before. Search engine sucks XD.